# constant string file in python

Tags: python, standards

I'm attempting to put all of my user facing strings into a single file to make changing those strings easier. I'm looking for a best practice in terms of readability. I have two version of the same file right now and I see trade off to both versions. So I was wondering if there's a best practice about this situation.

**First constants.py file**

```
class strings:

    esc_statuses = {
        "RETURNED": "Returned",
        "SUBMITTED": "Submitted",
        "DRAFT": "Draft",
        "CANCELED": "Canceled",
        "ESCALATED": "Escalated"
        }

    NewEscFieldText = {
        "customer_name": "The name of the customer who encountered this bug.",
        "summary": "A brief summary of the bug.",
        "request": "The request.",
        "customer_impact": "How the customer is impacted.",
        "severity": "The severity of the bug.",
        "component": "The component of this bug.",
        "related_bugs": "Bugs which are related to this one.",
        "logs": "The logs assosciated with this bug.",
        "description": "A detailed discription of the problem and any work \
                put into reproducting it.",
        "documentation": "Documentation consulted before escalation.",
        }
```

In the first version I'll have to say:

```
from constants import strings
```

and then whenever I want to reference something I'll have to say

```
strings.esc_statuses["RETURNED"]
```

I think the constants.py file looks more readable in this format but every time I have to use a string I'll have a much longer name to chew.

**Second constants.py file.**

```
class strings:

    # ------------------------ Escalation status -----------------------------
    RETURNED = "Returned"
    SUBMITTED = "Submitted"
    DRAFT =: "Draft"
    CANCELED =: "Canceled"
    ESCALATED =: "Escalated"

    # ----------------------- New Escalation Field Text ----------------------
    customer_name = "The name of the customer who encountered this bug."
    summary = "A brief summary of the bug."
    request = "The request."
    customer_impact = "How the customer is impacted."
    severity = "The severity of the bug."
    component = "The component of this bug."
    related_bugs = "Bugs which are related to this one."
    logs = "The logs assosciated with this bug."
    description = "A detailed discription of the problem and any work put \
            into reproducting it."
    documentation = "Documentation consulted before escalation."
```

In this version all I have to say is

```
from constants import strings
strings.RETURNED
```

Which I think makes using strings more readable but also makes the file itself harder to read.

So, are there any style guides that cover this? Are there any considerations I've missed?

Comment: Do you have the ability to load an external config file that contains the strings?

Comment: This file is supposed to be the external file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class stringer(type):
    esc_statuses = {
        "RETURNED": "Returned",
        "SUBMITTED": "Submitted",
        "DRAFT": "Draft",
        "CANCELED": "Canceled",
        "ESCALATED": "Escalated"
        }

    NewEscFieldText = {
        "customer_name": "The name of the customer who encountered this bug.",
        "summary": "A brief summary of the bug.",
        "request": "The request.",
        "customer_impact": "How the customer is impacted.",
        "severity": "The severity of the bug.",
        "component": "The component of this bug.",
        "related_bugs": "Bugs which are related to this one.",
        "logs": "The logs assosciated with this bug.",
        "description": "A detailed discription of the problem and any work \
                put into reproducting it.",
        "documentation": "Documentation consulted before escalation.",
        }

def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name in stringer.NewEscFieldText: 
        return stringer.NewEscFieldText[name]
    else:
        return stringer.esc_statuses[name]

class strings:
    __metaclass__ = stringer

print strings.customer_name
```

Comment: I feel stupid for not noticing this before, but `NewEscFieldText` is hard coded in the `__getattr__` function. This is going to be a large file by the time I'm done and I'm going to have many different dictionaries. My solution was to change `stringer.NewEscFieldText[name]` to `stringer.NewEscFieldText.get(name)` and check to see if it's null.